# Wordpress. Как настроить нормальный редирект в корзину с использованием Polylang

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Существует следующая проблема. Сайт / интернет-магазин реализован с использованием плагина - Polylang. Как можно сделать нормальный редирект.
А то получается, что после покупки всё равно кидает в корзину на русском языке. Вариации корзины созданы.

Comment: будет полезным включить **preserve log** в панели разработчика в chrome и убедиться в отсутствии еще каких-либо промежуточных редиректов

Comment: Только корзина волнуете? А письма, а другое :) В ответе плагин решающий эти и др задачи.

Answer (score 0):

> Сайт / интернет-магазин реализован с использованием плагина -
>   Polylang.

Для работы с WC у Polylang-а есть платное расширение (даже 2 по сути) https://polylang.pro/downloads/polylang-for-woocommerce/

https://polylang.pro/polylang-for-woocommerce/